# What does this notification mean?

Tags: translation, korean-to-english

My Android phone from Korea has run into some serious software issues and is now flashing the notification below:

[image: Notification]

My limited Korean knowledge cannot understand what this means, except that the title reads 'Android upgrade has stopped' or so. I'd really appreciate if someone can help me by explaining the meaning.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android is in the process of upgrading. (중 means "in the middle")

You have 139 apps (9 are being optimized), so it may take some time. Please don't let your phone run out of battery (charge).

Comment: Could you please tell what the number 9 refers to? It keeps increasing the count.

Comment: 9 are being "optimized"...I'm struggling a bit with exactly what that means...sorry.

Comment: It makes sense though. Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68207/discussion-on-answer-by-webjuju-what-does-this-notification-mean).